# After how many days will APNS mark a device as inactive?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushy

If a user has uninstalled my app, how long will the APNS take to update that this device is inactive for the bundleID?

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, after reading up a bunch to make the migration to the new APNS provider API, this is what seems most familiar to me regarding this:

[Establishing a Certificate-Based Connection to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_certificate-based_connection_to_apns?language=objc)

"Check expiry of a certificate with KeyChain Access. To avoid a disruption in service for your users, update your provider certificates before they expire. Provider certificates are valid for a year and must be updated to continue communicating with APNs".

Also:

"If you think your certificate or private key has been compromised, you can revoke your certificate from your developer account. APNs maintains a list of revoked certificates, and it refuses TLS connections from servers whose certificates are on that list. If your server is using a revoked certificate, close all existing connections to APNs and configure a new provider certificate for your server before opening any new connections".

Seems to me it the expiry is based around certificate creation as well as deleting the app?

I'd like to hear more on this....